# one function generating numbers for another

Tags: python, python-2.7, numbers, counter

I would like to create function that will count up & count down and I would like to access the counted value every let's say 500ms from another function.

How can I return this value 'a' every 500ms so I can read it externaly every e.g. 500ms ?

PS. I am using Python 2.7

This is my code so far with yield usage but it does not give what I want:

```
import time

class PLCApplication(object):
    def generate_data(self):
        a = 0
        countup = True
        while a >= 0:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            if countup == True:
                a += 2
            else:
                a -= 2
            if a < 0:
                countup = True
                a += 2
            if a == 12:
                countup = False
                a -= 2
            yield a

while True:
    plc = PLCApplication()
    b = plc.generate_data()
    for z in b:
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

print 'z...', z

---

EDIT:

This is the functionality I wanted to achieve. Thanks:

```
import time
from drawnow import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
plt.ion()

class PLCApplication(object):
    def generate_data(self):
        a = 0
        countup = True
        while a >= 0:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            if countup:  # no need to do test if it equals True
                a += 2
            else:
                a -= 2
            if a < 0:
                countup = True
                a += 2
            if a == 12:
                countup = False
                a -= 2
            yield a

    def makefig(self):
        plt.ylim(-10,30)
        plt.plot(x, 'ro-', label='testgraph')
        plt.grid(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plc = PLCApplication()
    cnt = 0
    for t in plc.generate_data():
        i = t
        x.append(int(i))
        cnt=cnt+1
        if cnt > 20:
            x.pop(0)
        print x, cnt
        drawnow(plc.makefig)
```

Comment: What is the requirement? Are you trying to generate a random number?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: roadrunner66: I would like to assign value a to e.g. value b in another function and update value b every e.g. 500ms. So, imagin function generate_data counts up every 500ms and increases value 'a' and in the same time another function reads 'generate_data' and assigns value of 'a' to value 'b' in that other function.

Comment: martineau: I should have made my question more clear. at the moment I generate value but I do not know how to access it externaly and read it in 'live' mode without breaking while loop. If I just run the code I pasted than I get into while loop and constantly count up count down ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: updated answer according to C14L's comment, original answer below.

```
import time

class PLCApplication(object):
    def generate_data(self):
        a = 0
        countup = True
        while a >= 0:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            if countup:  # no need to do test if it equals True
                a += 2
            else:
                a -= 2
            if a < 0:
                countup = True
                a += 2
            if a == 12:
                countup = False
                a -= 2
            yield a

def do_stuff(b):
    print b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plc = PLCApplication()
    for t in plc.generate_data():
        do_stuff(t)
```

---

Original answer:

You need to `print a` at an approriate place inside the `while` loop:

```
[...]
while a >= 0:
    print a
    time.sleep(0.5)
[...]
```

Comment: printing does not give me anything ? Should I think about something like threading instead ?

Comment: Do you want to print it, or actually return it?

Comment: as per my question: I want to return it during while & for loop so I can assign the value of 'a' to another value in another function while I loop through 'a' in generate_data function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read the later comments to your question just now. I'm afraid I can't help you with that. You need to search for asynchronous execution, I would be surprised if there were nothing for python 2.7...

Comment: Make the `print` a `yield`.

Comment: hi erip, I have updated my question with updated code with yield but I am not sure if I understand yield correctly but I do not get what I want. I need to do for..loop through yield'ed object in order to access values ...  I just simply want to get such functionality: when a = 2 then b in another fuction = 2, when a = 4 then b = 4 when a = 6 then b = 6 etc. etc. etc

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can loop through the `yield`ed values and for example pass it into another function

Comment: hi tschale, you answer helped me. I have just updated my question code with the code I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This example from the [Python Coroutine page](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#example-coroutine-displaying-the-current-date) seems to do that in a non-blocking way, using new `asyncio`.

```
import asyncio
import datetime

@asyncio.coroutine
def display_date(loop):
    end_time = loop.time() + 5.0
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        if (loop.time() + 1.0) >= end_time:
            break
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# Blocking call which returns when the display_date() coroutine is done
loop.run_until_complete(display_date(loop))
loop.close()
```

Comment: it returns SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It doesn't if you use at least Python 3.4 because `asyncio` and coroutines are very new.

Comment: ha, ok. how to do it in v2.7?

Comment: No idea, but you should maybe update your question and specify that you need it to work on 2.7 then.